# X and Y are not correlated, but Y is predictor of Xin random forests classifier. How to represent this using statistics and machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, non-linear-regression, mathematical-expressions

X and Y are not correlated (0.3); however, when I place X in random forests classifier predicting Y, alongside two (A, B) other (related) variables, X and two other variables (A, B) are significant predictors of Y. Note that the two other (A, B) variables are also not correlated with Y.
How can I interpret this according to statistics and machine learning idea.

Representing one or more variable (A, or B or Y) with respect to another variable (X), where the variables don't have a strong correlation.

Comment: This may be a better question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Correlations are linear.  If there’s a nonlinear relationship, you might see little or no correlation.

Random forests (and decision trees are nonlinear) so you could find a random forest predictive even if the correlation is zero.

[A quadratic function could have zero correlation between X and Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RvHR.gif)

This image and more on correlations can be found at 
https://www.statisticalengineering.com/correlation.htm